# Bug import boost library in QT on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, boost

I have a probleme with boost library in QT,

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0/lib/'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)", referenced from:
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() in genvtracking.o
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() (.cold.1) in genvtracking.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() in genvtracking.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() in genvtracking.o
  "boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() in genvtracking.o
  "boost::filesystem::path::filename() const", referenced from:
      GenvTracking::chargerModels() in genvtracking.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [untitled2.app/Contents/MacOS/untitled2] Error 1
09:34:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.5 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
09:34:34: Elapsed time: 00:02.

my .pro file
```

> INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0/include/"
>   LIBPATH += "-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0/lib/"

and my function:

```
void GenvTracking::chargerModels(){
    boost::filesystem::path p("..");
    for (auto i = boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p); i != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); i++)
        {
            if (!is_directory(i->path()))
            {
                models.push_back(i->path().filename().string());
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
}
```

I want to use boost for put values in a vector

Comment: From the warning `directory not found for option '-L-L/usr...` it looks like your build system prefixes  `LIBPATH` with `-L` automatically.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the `-L` from the beginning of your `LIBPATH` spec.?

Comment: You also need to link the lib, -L only adds a search path. Try `LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0/lib/ -lboost_filesystem` (note `LIBS`, not `LIBPATH`) Check the libfolder for the correct name of the lib, boost has some complex/funky naming scheme there.

Comment: Thanks you very much !!